# what is the difference between CSS Frameworks and CSS Grids

Tags: css

Please tell me the difference between CSS Frameworks and CSS Grids.

Comment: You can ask this question here http://doctype.com/

Answer (score 1):

CSS Framework can also be CSS Grid Framework. CSS Grid Frameworks are used for building CSS Layout. There are some frameworks who have other purpose then building layouts, example Hartija http://code.google.com/p/hartija/ is build for web printing.

Also the word "Framework" or "CSS Framework" is not precisely defined, there is one part of the CSS Community who believes that CSS Framework can be only CSS Layout system and the other part refers to any CSS Library.

Answer (score 0):

- CSS Grid is *specification* (set of rules which browser has to follow and understand). It's like a language between you and browser.
- CSS Framework is like a *wrapper*, which includes set of specification,like CSS Grids, Flexbox, CSS2/3 and so on, which provide additional features. 
  For example: build a layout by grid. CSS Frameworks have own syntax, but actually it's just syntax sugar, which uses CSS specification the the code anyway.